# Storing current time in timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, knockout.js

I wanted to add a new field to my current system, a last_pwd_modified field, which will store the current timestamp in db whenever user wanted to change their password.

I'm having a problem debugging this for hours since the last_pwd_modified field won't store the current time in db and also a 500 (Internal Server Error) keep occurring. I think it might be the way the last_pwd_modified being pass is wrong, I tried several other ways passing it but keep failing.

Could anyone expert maybe pointed out what seems to be the problem in my code. Really appreciate it and a thank you in advance for your time.

**Here is my model**

```
 public function changePasswd($uid, $newpassword) {
    $conditions=array();
    $modelData = array(
            'upwd' => sha1(strip_tags($newpassword)),
            'uid' => $uid,
            'last_pwd_modified' => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"
    );
    $this->save($modelData);    
}
```

**Here is a line in my controller which call the function**

```
$this->users->changePasswd($uid,$ret_pwd);
```

**And here is my viewModel**

```
var changePassword = function () {
    var $result = {};
        $.ajax({
            url: "users/changepwd",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: $("#changePasswordID").serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $result = $.parseJSON(result);
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` does not take an argument.

Comment: I tried this **'last_pwd_modified' => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"** in the first place still having the same error. Maybe you know another reason?

Comment: I would set default value with internal mysql trigger. In table definition: `CREATE TABLE .... LAST_MOD ... DEFAULT NOW()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp). `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns date like`Y-m-d H:i:s`. Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` without argument.

Also, your Database lib could use prepared statement or escaping. Probably you cannot use mysql function as value. I thinkg you could try  `'last_pwd_modified' => time()`.